# Cannot add Google Maps in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I want to use various Google services in an Android app I am working on, such as Google Maps, Google Directions and Google Geolocation. I have followed the steps described in [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) in order to get and Android API Key and I got one. I now try to add something very simple to my app, but it cannot even import package `com.google. ...` .

My `Android.Manifest` file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="di.uoa.gr.e_commerce" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InitialActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_initial" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeleteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_delete" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SeeCartActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_see_cart" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ModifyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_modify" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.AndroidKey"
        android:value="xxx (my key)"/>

</application>
```

In the file `MainActivity.java` I try to import :

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
```

but `google` is underlined with red saying :

> Cannot resolve symbol Google.

I am sure I am missing something but can't figure out what.

Comment: have you added play services in gradle file?

Comment: @VivekMishra no, I didn't see anywhere about that. Could you explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add Library dependancy:
  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0

permissions:
 <permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Could you please explain where I can find the module you propose?

Comment: cntrl+shift+Alt+s-->select project-->dependencis-->click"+"icon-->Library dependancy-->choose com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0 @Marievi

Comment: The latest version I find is 6.5.87.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this site and can add Google maps to your project by single line of code
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup